# Hover animation in framer motion. text getting visually distorted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I am new to framer motion and I want to make a hover animation on the button. I  was able to create the animation successfully but when I hover over the button the text gets distorted and I want to fix it, I have done research but i wasn't able to find a solution

I want to apply animation only to the button not the text inside it

I have tried adding `<motion.button layout />`

I have tried adding `<motion.button layout="position" />`

I have also added `<span>button text</span>`

but the issue is still there

```
     <motion.button
        style={{
          padding: "10px 30px",
          border: "none",
          marginTop: "20px"
        }}
        whileHover={{
          scale: 1.1
        }}
        whileTap={{
          scale: 0.9
        }}
      >
        Button
      </motion.button>
```

It would be great if someone would help me in fixing this issue,
https://codesandbox.io/s/late-darkness-ejuzt?file=/src/App.js:134-419 is my code sandbox link where u can see what I'm saying

thanks!

Comment: What do you mean under *the text gets distorted*? It makes text bigges scaling as a button. Do you like to fix keep it small?

Comment: Yes @IlliaChil I want to keep the text same, and NOT scale it with the button, but the thing is, when i scale the button, the text is getting bigger  as well, I only want to animate the parent and not child

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67477219/animate-scalex-in-framer-motion-without-affecting-childrens-scale), you can't 'disable' scaling for child components with framer. Try to use react components and variables (or CSS) to disable child scaling.